# How can I get Azure resource cost by location using C#?

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to get cost of Azure resources by location using C# with the following code:

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(<clientid>, <secret>, <tenantid>, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var consumptionClient = new ConsumptionManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = <subscription_id>};

var usageDetails = consumptionClient.UsageDetails.List("filter=properties/usageStart eq '2024-02-01' and properties/usageEnd eq '2022-02-28' and properties/instanceLocation eq 'West Europe'");

foreach (var usageDetail in usageDetails)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Resource: {usageDetail.Id}, Cost: {usageDetail.PretaxCost}");
}
```

But it seems to never go past `var usageDetails`, it sits there forever.

Any ideas as to why this may happen or how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

**Use below C# code to fetch Azure resources cost data by location:**

```cs
string subscriptionId = "your-subscription-id";

var serviceCreds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(
    "your-tenant-id", "your-client-id", "your-client-secret");

ConsumptionManagementClient client = new ConsumptionManagementClient(serviceCreds)
{
     SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
};

string startDate = "2024-01-01";
string endDate = "2024-01-31";

var usageDetails = await client.UsageDetails.ListAsync(
    "$filter=usageStart ge '" + startDate + "' and usageEnd le '" + endDate + "'");

var usageByLocation = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
foreach (var detail in usageDetails)
{
    string location = detail.InstanceLocation;
    decimal cost = detail.PretaxCost ?? 0; // Handle nullable decimal
    if (!usageByLocation.ContainsKey(location))
       usageByLocation[location] = 0;
    usageByLocation[location] += cost;
}

// Fetch the costs by location
foreach (var location in usageByLocation)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Location: {location.Key}, Total Cost: {location.Value}");
}
```

**Note: Assign *Reader Role* to the service principal to fetch the required cost details.**

[image]

**Response:**

- Able to fetch the cost details of resources by Location:

[image]

Comment: I get an error on line "var usageDetails...."  Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest  ?

Comment: Check if all the values are valid and also `Start Date` and `End Date`.

Comment: Yes i have checked the values are valid and also the star and end date are of the format , yyyy-mm-dd ?

Comment: Did you assign Reader Role to the service principal as shown above?

Comment: I am running the app from powershell on my local machine , how do i assign it

Comment: You have to assign in the Azure portal. Refer first Image.

Comment: which image do i refer too ?

Comment: I meant first [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/R7vYmd0.png) in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257085/discussion-between-melissa-and-pravallika-kv).